# SQLITE: Multiple foreign key referenced to multiple table cascade delete

Tags: sqlite, foreign-keys, cascading-deletes

In SQLite I would like to delete parent table row and it has to delete all the related child tables. I have gone through all the questions in StackExchange and other websites but my query no where satisfied.

I have four tables.

```
TableA:
id, primary key
name

TableB:
id, primary key
issues,
tb_aid, #foreign key ref to TableA id
tb_cid, #foreign key ref to TableC id
tb_did, #foreign key ref to TableD id
tb_eid, #foreign key ref to TableE id

TableC:
id, primary key
column1,
tb_bid, #foreign key ref to TABLE B id

TableD:
id,
name

TableE
id,
name
```

I tried JOIN but unfortunately its not working in SQLite. I dont know how to use `TRIGGER`. Is it possible to use `ON CASCADE DELETE` for the above case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use cascading deletion here.  For example, for `TableC`, you might use the following definition:

```
CREATE TABLE TableC (
    id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
    column1 TEXT,
    tb_bid INTEGER NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT fk_b FOREIGN KEY (tb_bid) REFERENCES TableB (id) ON DELETE CASCADE
)
```

The purpose of the constraint in the above table definition is that it links the `tb_bid` column as a foreign key pointing to the primary key `id` column in `TableB`.  This means that if a parent record in `TableB` gets deleted, SQLite will cascade that deletion down to all child records in `TableC`.

You might define your `TableB` as follows:

```
CREATE TABLE TableB (
    id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
    issues TEXT,
    tb_aid INTEGER NOT NULL,
    tb_cid INTEGER NOT NULL,
    tb_did INTEGER NOT NULL,
    tb_eid INTEGER NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT fk_a FOREIGN KEY (tb_aid) REFERENCES TableA (id) ON DELETE CASCADE,
    CONSTRAINT fk_c FOREIGN KEY (tb_cid) REFERENCES TableC (id) ON DELETE CASCADE,
    CONSTRAINT fk_d FOREIGN KEY (tb_did) REFERENCES TableD (id) ON DELETE CASCADE,
    CONSTRAINT fk_e FOREIGN KEY (tb_eid) REFERENCES TableE (id) ON DELETE CASCADE
)
```

Comment: It works fine. Thank you. Suppose if the TableC doesn't point to TableB and TableB is having 3 foreign keys of 3 different table what could be the solution?

Comment: Then you need three `CONTRAINT` entires in your create table statement.  Other than that, nothing else needs to change.

Comment: all 3 `CONSTRAINT` in TableB or in each table during the table creation?